# How can I arrange this 3D array data if its randomly written

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, 3d

I have a data for electricity, its arranged as the following
room     timing 1      timing 2.        timing 3      timing 4        timing 5         timing6
1          34.5.         22.1.            34.2           0              45              0
2         42.1             31.2            4.1           0              21              1
and so on.

it is saved as a .txt file. I am trying to import the data into python and find the minimum and the maximum value and the average of each room. then find the maximum and the minimum of electricity in each room. My only struggle is I don't know to arrange my data in a way I can make it a list without taking the numbers themselves and putting them into a list for example room1= [ 34.5, 22.1, 34.2, 0, 45, 0]. I don't want to do it that way. This is by the way a 3D array which I never worked with. Can someone please help me arrange my data in a way I can find mini and max and average without using the method I listed above?

Comment: Can you paste some more data from the data file such that we can reproduce the same

Comment: 20 1.54543e-12 1.54543e-12 1.54543e-12 1.54543e-12 1.54543e-12 0 0 0
21 27.1157 149.157 176.206 183.932 131.259 5.05759 0 0
22 1.31095e-12 1.31095e-12 1.31095e-12 1.31095e-12 7.76349e-13 0 0 0
24 1.36779e-12 1.36779e-12 1.36779e-12 1.36779e-12 1.36779e-12 0 0 0
25 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing your data is a single string separated by spaces inside a single file.

This is supposed to load the data parts by parts in memory process it and dump it to file in which you will have a room and their X time intervals per line.

```
input_filename = "./input.txt"
output_filename = "./output.txt"
entries = []
rooms = []
time_intervals = 6
buff = ""
max_rooms_on_mem = 1

def flush_rooms(rooms): 
  with open(output_filename, 'a') as fo:
    for room in rooms:
        fo.write(' '.join([str(x) for x in room]))
        fo.write('\n')
    fo.close()

with open(input_filename) as fi:
  while True:
    c = fi.read(1)
    if not c:
      print("End of file")
      break
    if c != " ":
      buff += c
    else: 
      entries.append(float(buff))
      buff = ""

    if len(entries) == time_intervals:
      rooms.append(entries)
      entries = []

    if len(rooms) == max_rooms_on_mem:
      flush_rooms(rooms)
      rooms = []
  fi.close()

flush_rooms(rooms)
```

Your input file should look something like this...

```
34.5 22.1 34.2 0 45 0 2 42.1 31.2 4.1 0 21 1
```

And your output file will look something like this...

```
34.5 22.1 34.2 0.0 45.0 0.0
2.0 42.1 31.2 4.1 0.0 21.0
```

You can use `time_intervals` to determine how many time intervals a room should have.
And you can use `max_rooms_on_mem` to determine how many rooms should be kept in memory until the next flush... this way you won't overload your memory.

If you just want to work with all the `rooms` in memory you can just set `max_rooms_on_mem=-1` the results will never be flushed.

Otherwise, you can work with the output file where a room is represented by a line.

I hope this can help you

Comment: the probelm is i cant use file_data as I have a lot of data. is there any way I can arrange it like import the file and arrange it?

Comment: You could use a buffer and do this step by step... but how much data are we talking about? Depending on the amount I would suggest to write the rooms array to a file or database... to clear the memory...

Comment: 50 rooms. 8 time intervals. I dont have the data saved in a .txt file, however, I am not sure how can I access it if its not in a table or list its just floating. that's what I need help with.

Comment: Okay. Since you don't have the data I suppose you can go with your ideia of saving it to TXT file in a single line. I've edited the answer so you can output a file with the arranged data where 1 line in the output file is equal to 1 room time intervals. I've also added a buffer so you won't run out of mem.